# Schlag, Seite, Schlagseite

Tags: etymology, technical-terminology

Ich habe grad gelesen, ***Schlag*** sei

> ... *der theil der leeseite eines schiffes beim groszen hals oder der fockrüste, so genannt, weil die wellen besonders gegen diese stelle schlagen, wenn das schiff bei dem winde segelt* Bobrik 601a"

> (Grimm/DWB: [schlag](https://dwds.de/wb/dwb/schlag), V 5.),

womit ich auch noch nicht viel anfangen kann.

Daneben steht noch Nynorsk *slag*, s.v. "bilge": "(nautical) The rounded portion of a ship's hull, forming a transition between the bottom and the sides." ([https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bilge#English])

Ferner steht bei Grimm

> e) dicke planke, die an die unterkante des steuerruders gebolzt wird, damit dieses tiefer ins wasser reicht. ebenda".

aber zu einer Schräglage führt das höchstens im Unfall nur für kurze Zeit.

In anderem Sinne steht zu *Schlag* natürlich noch mehr. Was ist nun richtig?

Comment: Kannst du deine Frage bitte etwas präzisieren? Kann nicht alles richtig sein? (auch wenn ich das mit der Planke am Ruder abwegig empfinde)

Comment: Davon abgesehen: Schlagseite kommt sehr sicher nicht daher, dass man *eine* Bordwand verstärkt hat - das hat man mit beiden gemacht. Aber wenn man der Logik mit der Verbindung zu Nynorsk Slak (=Bilge) folgt, so ist logisch, dass das Schiff Schlagseite hat, wenn die Wellen gegen die Bilge schlagen (die normalerweise unterhalb der Wasserlinie ist und zu sein hat).

Comment: @planetmaker Stimme natürlich zu, dass eine Seite an einem Schiff sicher nicht anders ist als die andere - Es hat ja nicht immer den Wind auf derselben Seite.

Comment: Ich wundere mich gerade etwas darüber, dass die Wellen vornehmlich gegen die *Leeseite* des Schiffs schlagen sollen. Da der Wind von Luv kommt, hätte ich erwartet, dass *dort* die meisten/stärkeren Wellen auftreffen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die Leeseite ist ja "das Stück Wasser", das den Druck der Segel aufnimmt und ins Wasser weitergibt - Eine Kraft, die größer sein  muss als die Kraft auf der Luvseite, damit das Schiff überhaupt fährt. Das ist schon logisch. Wenn das Schiff nicht unter Segeln steht, sondern einfach nur so rumdümpelt, hast du allerdings recht - aber das ist ja nicht Sinn und Zweck eines Segelschiffs.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper es mag kontra-intuitiv sein, ist aber tatsächlich so bei einem *segelnden* Schiff - eine Eigenschaft, die man für alle Hochseeschiffe voraussetzen konnte zur Zeit als der Begriff geprägt wurde. Ein Segelschiff unter Segel fährt nicht nur durch das Wasser sondern wird auch immer in einer Art vom Wind getrieben - der Wind, der meist auch die Wellen treibt. Im sogenannten Beilieger wird es besonders klar: man kann selbst bei rauher See ziemlich ruhig für eine Verschnaufpause liegen, weil man quasi vor Wellen und Wind wegtreibt. Siehe bspw. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-JAGpADSHY

Comment: @tofro: Ach so, es geht also nicht um die Wellen, die von starkem Wind gegen das Schiff geworfen werden, sondern um die Wellen, die ohnehin da sind, die aber härter auf den oberen Teil der Bordwand treffen, da das Schiff dort tiefer im Wasser liegt. Verstehe.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Nicht genau "weil das Schiff dort tiefer im Wasser liegt": Im Prinzip üben die Wellen sowohl auf der Lee- als auch auf der Luvseite dieselbe Kraft auf das Schiff aus (es sind ja sozusagen "dieselben" Wellen) - Auf der Leeseite kommt aber noch die wesentlich größere gesammelte Kraft der Segel dazu, weil der Wind auf dieser Seite das Schiff über die Segel gegen die Wellen drückt.

Answer (score 4):

Deine Frage *»Was ist nun richtig?«* beruht offenbar auf der Annahme, dass nur eine der beiden Bedeutungen richtig wäre. Es gibt aber keinen Grund, das anzunehmen.

Das Wort *Schlag* hat sehr viele Bedeutungen: Ein Schlag ins Gesicht, etwas Schlag zur Torte, der Schlag der Nachtigall, der Schlag am Bein einer Hose, der Schlag in dem man Tauben züchtet usw. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schlag) listet 19 verschiedene Bedeutungen für dieses Substantiv, ich vermute aber, dass diese Liste bei weitem nicht vollständig ist. Insbesondere glaube ich, dass viele veraltete Ausdrücke und Ausdrücke aus Fachsprachen noch fehlen.

Daher würde es mich nicht wundern, wenn beide von dir beschriebenen Bedeutungen korrekt wären. Ich kenne beide Bedeutungen nicht, das heißt aber nicht viel, denn ich lebe in einem Binnenland, da hat man mit Marine nicht viel am Hut. Ich kannte aus der Wiktionary-Liste auch nur einen der drei dort gelisteten seemännischen Ausdrücke. (Die gesegelte Strecke zwischen zwei Wenden und die nichtverknotete Schlinge eines Taus kannte ich nicht. Ich kannte nur die Bewegung des Paddels beim Rudern.)

Generell ist die Annahme, ein bestimmtes Wort würde nur eine bestimmte Sache bedeuten, fast immer falsch. Fast jedes Wort hat mehrere Bedeutungen. Es gibt aber auch zu jeder Bedeutung fast immer mehrere Worte, die diese Bedeutung haben. Das ist in allen lebenden Sprachen so.

Comment: Die Überschrift ist etwas verwirren geworden, weil "Schlagseite" allein das 15 Zeichen Gebot nicht erreicht hat. Darauf bezieht sich die Frage letztendlich aber, s. "Schräglage", und leitet deswegen damit ein.

Comment: Sorry, aber das ist keine Antwort, sondern ein etwas ausufernder Kommentar. Du schreibst es ja selbst: "... würde es mich nicht wundern, wenn ...". Da das aber ein ziemlich guter Kommentar ist, werte ich diese Antwort nicht ab. Vielleicht magst du es selbst in einen Kommentar umwandeln?

Comment: @vectory: Dass nicht Schlag, sondern Schlagseite gemeint war, kommt aus der Frage leider nicht klar hervor. Vor allem die erste Zeile (*»Ich habe grad gelesen, **Schlag** sei«*) lenkt die Aufmerksamkeit doch sehr auf das Wort Schlag. Und die 15 Zeichen hättest du locker überschritten, wenn du in der Überschrift eine Frage formuliert hättest, also einen vollständigen Satz, der mit einem Fragezeichen endet, z.B. *»Welche Bedeutung hat das Wort Schlagseite?«* (42 Zeichen). Wenn du unklare Fragen stellst, darfst du den Antwortenden nicht die Schuld für Missverständnisse geben.

Answer (score 3):

Natürlich können beide Bedeutungen richtig sein, wie Hubert schon geschrieben hat.

Beide Bedeutungen haben auch *denselben* Grund (nämlich dass ein Schiff unter Segeln, wenn der Wind von der Seite kommt, eben nicht mehr senkrecht im Wasser steht). Aus diesem Grund werden sowohl die Bordwände an der Stelle, wo die Wellen dagegen *schlagen*, verstärkt, als auch das Ruderblatt verlängert und verstärkt (weil es bei Schräglage nicht mehr so tief ins Wasser ragt und deshalb an Wirkung verliert).

Ein *Schlag* ist heute beim Segeln hauptsächlich die gerade Strecke zwischen zwei Wendepunkten. Während man einen *Schlag macht*, steht das Schiff nicht senkrecht (das ist ja die Absicht, dass man möglichst viel Wind mitnimmt). Dass alles, was daraus folgt, irgendwas mit *Schlag* heißt, ist nur natürlich.

Dass die Grimms als Binnenländler nicht gerade mit der seemännischen Ausdrucksweise und der Funktion von Schiffen vertraut waren, mag durchaus entschuldigen, dass die Erklärung, nunja, ein bisschen *lau* ist.

Comment: Die Brüder Grimm stammen aus Hanau in Hessen, das liegt in der Mitte Deutschlands. Deutschland ist aber kein Binnenland. Es grenzt an die Nordsee und an die Ostsee. Auch wenn es richtig ist, dass es Deutschland als politische Einheit erst seit 1871 gibt, und die Brüder Grimm vor dieser Zeit lebten, halte ich die Aussage, sie wären Binnenländler gewesen, für gewagt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Hessen ist eine berühmte Seefahrernation"? Es liegt in jeder Richtung an die 500km vom Meer weg, was für mich durchaus das Kriterium "Binnenland" erfüllt. Ich würde spekulieren, dass die einzige Berührung mit Schifffahrt, die die Grimms jemals hatten, ein Paddelboot auf dem Main gewesen sein dürfte. Sieht man die Sache aus linguistischer und nicht aus geografischer Sicht, dann ist es so, dass die nautische Sprache im Deutschen sehr vom norddeutschen Platt, vom Holländischen und vom Englischen geprägt ist - Alles Sprachen, die regional von den Grimms auch weit entfernt waren.

Comment: ... Nur ein paar wahllos herausgegriffene Stichproben: Wäre das Grimmsche Wörterbuch ein nautisches, sollte es zumindestens die Begriffe *achtern* (kennt es gar nicht), *Bug* (kennt es als Körperteil eines Pferdes), *Fock* (kennt es gar nicht) oder *Spill* (kennt es nur außerhalb von Schiffen) kennen.

Comment: Extra für dich als Österreicher: Hanau und Kassel, wo die Grimms lebten, liegen ungefähr gleich weit weg von der Küste wie Wien....

Comment: Mag schon sein, und zu Österreich gehörten bis 1918 auch Teile der Adriaküste, und Österreich hatte auch eine Marine. Immerhin hat auch ein Österreicher (der Böhme Josef Ressel) die Schiffsschraube erfunden. (Ressel war eigentlich Förster, arbeitete aber für die österr. Kriegsmarine in Triest.) Aber trotzdem ist Österreich seit etwas mehr als 100 Jahren ein [Binnenstaat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binnenstaat) und Deutschland war es niemals, egal welches historische Gebiet man als "Deutschland" bezeichnet. Und Hessen ist auch keine Nation sondern ein Bundesland.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja, und die Niederlande liegen in der Karibik....

Comment: Bei den Niederlanden kann ich das nicht genau sagen, aber Frankreich (und damit die EU) liegt zum Teil in der Karibik. Wie genau das bei der Definition von *»Binnenstaat«* weiterhelfen soll, erschließt sich mir aber leider nicht.

Comment: Der Band mit *Schlag* erschien lange nach dem Tod der Brüder Grimm und wurde nicht von ihnen bearbeitet: http://dwb.uni-trier.de/de/das-woerterbuch/die-baende-des-dwb/

Comment: Es gehört schon Absicht dazu, aus "Die Grimms als Binnenländer" "Deutschland liegt nicht am Meer" zu lesen. Die Bedeutung liegt doch klar auf der Hand ohne einen Wettbewerb im Erbsenzählen auszurufen...